# Easiest way to create accounts for users

Tags: iphone, users, accounts

I am currently creating an iPhone app, and I'm almost done with the whole process.

One of the last features I'd like to add is for users to be able to review an object, rate it (on a scale of 1-5), and leave a short comment.

The only problem is that I've done everything to avoid a user having to create an account. I want to keep it as simple as possible, so whenever the user would launch the app, they wouldn't have to log in, there is no account creation and worrying about passwords, etc...

The only information that could actually interest me is what country the user comes from, but I don't need a username, an email or a picture.

Is it easier for the user to create an account or is there a realistic way of implementing a review system without one?

Comment: Can't you track the country based on IP address?

Comment: I probably can, but that doesn't really resolve the whole issue...Do I just ask a simple username and nothing more? I really don't know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I’d suggest a simple feedback form, where users can select their country, press any star (1-5) and add an optional comment. If you don’t need a user account, don’t implement it. Your users probably already have too many accounts they need to keep track of.

This way you just ask for feedback in the simplest way possible. Make sure that you save the country the user choses the first time if they will review more than one object.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOthDA.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for this reply, it's a really interesting option in my opinion. I may even, as @JohnGB suggested below, directly find the country through the user's IP address... My only issue is: does a review have lest credibility when there is no "username" or picture associated to the user?

Answer (score 1):

You can **use the devices regional settings** to get the country that the person has set up, and pre-fill in the country field with that, or even not expose the country field and just use that as is.  However you may then need more permissions than your app currently asks for, which you should try to avoid.

If you don't need 100% accurate data for countries (which you won't get anyway with a selector), I would simply track the IP address that the HTTP submission came from on the server and **use a GeoIP tool** to translate that into a country.  This is accurate enough for most purposes.

Whichever option you choose, it will mean less interaction needed by users to send feedback, which usually results in more users sending feedback.

Comment: I've looked around a bit and found a couple of GeoIP tools for iOS. That's probably the solution I am going to use for the country. Only thing I'm afraid of is, as I said above, the credibility of a review that has no username/name/picture associated.